# HTML5 player In SharePoint 2007 webpart is not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, audio, sharepoint-2007, html5-audio

I am using the HTML5 audio tag to create a player within a SharePoint 2007 webpart. It works fine in both Chrome and Firefox but it will not work in IE (11) at all. Below is the code that I am using.

```html
<div>   
    <img src="bgImageforPlayer.jpg" width="300" height="136">
</div>
<div>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source src="music.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="music.wav" type="audio/x-wav">   
    </audio>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which document mode is your site using? You can check by opening the F12 Developer Tools, or by logging `document.documentMode`.

Comment: I'm using Edge. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, thank you. When you say it's "not working," what exactly is it doing? Do you see errors in the console in the Developer Tools? Are there any 404's in the Network panel of the Developer Tools? Are you loading this file via a server, or from your desktop via the `file://` protocol? Can you put this online someplace for testing?

Comment: There are no 404 messages. I am self-taught so i might not be very good at detecting error messages but when I view the page it via the Developer Tools, I do not see any. I am loading the file through SharePoint's server and the code is loaded into the source editor in SharePoint.

Comment: The page displays only the image div, it does not display any of the audio controls. Thanks again!

Comment: In the DOM Explorer of you Developer Tools, are you able to locate (via expanding elements, and their children) the `<audio>` element? Either way, a screenshot of your DOM Explorer with all *relevant* elements expanded would be helpful.

Comment: You can use the [Snipping Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool) to take a picture of your browser or developer tools. You can then return here, [edit] your question, and insert the image into the bottom of your post by clicking the [Image icon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVPdb.png).

Comment: If you are unable to post the image here, upload it to http://imgur.com, and link to it from your post.

Comment: http://imgur.com/MeUjIYw][img]http://i.imgur.com/MeUjIYw.png

Comment: I've added your image to the above post; you can delete the last two comments :) Can you share a screenshot of your *actual source code*? Feel free to change the path to your .mp3 files for the screenshot if you'd like to keep that information private.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/a8Lf8wK.png

Comment: 1) You're missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>` at the beginning. 2) The `<meta...>` element should be removed (or change `IE=10` to `IE=Edge`). 3) There is a `</a>` after your image that needs to be removed. --- please make these changes and let me know if they improve the experience any.

Comment: made the changes but the issue persists. do you believe this could have something to do with SharePoint 2007? I am not an SP developer, I only have the rights to create and edit sites, pages etc...from themes and templates already created by the developers.

Comment: It is entirely possible; does the code work if you put it into its own HTML file and view in the browser?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. It works if i just launch it in the browser without putting the code into SharePoint. Thank you, Jonathan!

Comment: I suspect the document mode of the SharePoint site (not your webpart) may be preventing your document from working correctly. Which document mode is enabled in the Emulation panel of the Developer Tools for the site itself?

Comment: Right again. It's IE 5 and that's the default. Are these editable? (as the site is built off of templates and themes created by our developers)

Comment: The document mode is editable, but you'll need access to either the template code, or be able to configure server response headers. That being said, there is a small chance that it's using the IE 5 document mode for a reason, which would be bad for us.